# Do Gauge Theories (CFTs) Have Phase Transitions as the 't Hooft Coupling is Varied?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, research-level, ads-cft

With an eye toward AdS/CFT, I'm wondering if large $N$ CFTs have a (quantum) phase transition as the 't Hooft coupling is varied.  To be more specific -- if I look at correlation functions of low-dimension, single trace operators as a function of $\lambda$, are they analytic, continuous, discontinuous in $\lambda$?  How much do we know / any references?  I'm already aware of [0811.3001](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3001).

Comment: I can't edit, but making stuff like 0811.3001 hyperlinks would be nice.

Comment: I've made it appear.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is very well-posed, since most large-N theories aren't going to exist at multiple values of the 't Hooft coupling. (QCD is asymptotically free, for example, so it's always a "small-$\lambda$" theory in this sense.) ${\cal N}=4$ SYM is an example where the gauge coupling is an exactly marginal direction, so it really exists at all $\lambda$. That's the only setting where I think the question is really well-defined, and as far as I'm aware there is no quantum phase transition, just a smooth change as $\lambda$ varies.

Comment: @MattReece Can you give some references which analyze the phase-transitions of $\cal{N}=4$ SYM? To start-off I have seen - http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/hep-th/pdf/0612/0612073v2.pdf, http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/hep-th/pdf/0303/0303207v1.pdf I would be glad to see something more expository.

Answer (score 9):

The example i know does not use 't Hooft's coupling, but i think it may address your question in a more straightforward way (i'll be "loose" with constants and numerical pre-factors, but will keep all the relevant info and details).

Think of a 0-dimensional scalar field (bosonic $D0$-brane) with a quartic potential à la $V(\phi) = \mu\,\phi^2 + \lambda\,\phi^4$. And, if you allow me some *poetic license* with polynomials, let me rewrite this potential in the following form: $V_g(\phi) = \phi^2 + g\,\phi^4$, where $g=\lambda/\mu$, and it should be clear that "large $g$" means "strong coupling", while "small $g$" means "weak coupling".

The Partition Function (Feynman Path Integral) for this function is given by,

$$
\mathcal{Z}_g[J] = \int e^{i\, S_g(\phi)}\,e^{i\,J\,\phi}\,\mathrm{d}\phi < \infty\; ;
$$
where $S_g[\phi] = V_g(\phi)$ is the Action of the system (where i'm keeping the coupling constant explicit), and the requirement is that the integral *converges* (so the Partition Function is "well defined" in some sense).

But, there's a differential version of the above, called the Schwinger-Dyson equation, given by,

$$
\frac{\partial S_g(\phi)}{\partial\phi} = 0 \;\Longleftrightarrow\; \mu\,\phi + \lambda\,\phi^3 = 0 \;\Longleftrightarrow\; \phi\,(1 + g\,\phi^2) = 0\;;
$$
remembering that $\phi\mapsto\partial_J=\partial/\partial J$, giving us the following:

$$
(\partial_J + g\,\partial_J^3)\,\mathcal{Z}(J) = J\;.
$$

From this differential equation you clearly know one thing: there are 3 solutions to the above problem. This implies that each solution admits an integral representation, which is the Partition Function associated with that particular solution.

In fact, each $\mathcal{Z}_g(J)$ is defined within a certain Stokes' wedge, meaning that when you cross a Stokes' line you pick up some non-trivial constant contribution (very much à la wall-crossing phenomena).

Moreover, you can write the solutions to the above in terms of [confluent] hypergeometric functions (or, if you will, in terms of Meijer's G-function, or Fox's H-function) and distinguish its PolyLogarithm contribution, which is related to its singularity (pole) structure, and can be a big deal when talking about perturbation theory.

Anyway, this is just a "crash-core-dump" version of what i believe attacks your question; the point being that $g$ labels your "quantum phases". Note that it's possible to extend the field from scalar-valued to vector-, matrix-, tensor-, and Lie Algebra-valued: all the results mentioned go through with minor modifications (such as tracing appropriate variables, etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to be clear: When you say "each $Z_g(J)$ is defined within a certain Stokes' wedge", do you mean in the source $J$ or in the (complexified) coupling $g$? Are the multiple solutions connected via $g$ alone, or is it also necessary to change the boundary conditions?